# How to change the variable value dynamically?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having following variables in my powershell script

```
$Buildlog="FormalBuild.log"
$Logger="/flp1:Append;LogFile=$Buildlog;Verbosity=Diag;"

#Logger will use Formalbuild.log
Write-host $logger 

$Buildlog="Dailybuild.log"

#Logger should use Dailybuild.log file
Write-host $logger
```

$logger always displays Formalbuild.log. I do not want to redefine logger again. Is there any way to make the $logger value dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for example here: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/10/31/creating-intelligent-variables.aspx

Then the code snippet might be:

```
$Buildlog="FormalBuild.log"

$logger = Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable logger -Mode Read -Action { $global:logger = "/flp1:Append;LogFile=$Buildlog;Verbosity=Diag;" }

#Logger will use Formalbuild.log
Write-host $logger 

$Buildlog="Dailybuild.log"

#Logger should use Dailybuild.log file
Write-host $logger
```